# Parsing the terminal like arguments and parameters from a string in node for a fake terminal website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, command-line-arguments

I have a string `command` in my nextjs project([source](https://github.com/mind0bender/phew/tree/00e578e477c09b41d42353a2871e7592f18ed053)) and I want to get all the arguments(if any) and parameters(if any) from it in an array and object respectively.

for example:

```
const command = "login 'username' -p 'secret password' --save";
```

then I want the output to be like;

```
{
  args: ['username'],
  params:{
    p: 'secret password',
    save: true,
  }
}
```

> note: I can do this in client or on server on [my fake terminal site](https://phew-nf9z2p21l-mind0bender-m0b.vercel.app/) but I would prefer the client side.

I tried [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) but it gives error  `can not find module fs` as
I am using [nextjs](https://nextjs.org/) and I think it is made for real terminal arguments received from `process.argv` and not for a string.

I also tried making a function to parse it but could not think of a good solution that would work for all arguments and parameters combinations in an optimal way.

You can see the updated deployment on [phew](https://phew.vercel.app/)